# ACTION_UP not being called

Tags: android

I've got an `ImageView` that I'd like to dim to `.5f` Alpha when the user touches it, and fade back to `1.0f` after the finger is lifted.

```
 ok.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
                    {


                            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                            arg0.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        }
                        else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        {
                            arg0.setAlpha(0.5f);

                        }

                            return false;
                    }


                });
```

"ok" is the name of my `ImageView`. If I'm doing something wrong here, fill me in. I wonder if it's because the alpha change makes the `ImageView` not clickable?

Comment: When you do a debug, does the cursor step into the if statements correctly when you press and lift your finger?  That's the first thing to make sure of. If it is stepping into the proper logic, then it's a problem with the view itself.  Alpha changes won't change the cilckability of the view.  Does it fade to half opacity when you press?

Comment: if you `return false;`,Action up would not call so return `true`  on `onTouch()`